# How to get Data from AngularJS using a scope with different kinds of Properties?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have assigned to an scope object an object (class) but this class has two attributes: two arrays and two strings, how can I get the values from this `$scope`?

Ex: Object to Assign:

```
    var Address = new List<string> { "460 jones", "560 Ultimo" };
    var Telefonos = new List<string> { "0450003514", "046007989" };
     var SettingsDetails = new SettingsDetails
       {
           Name = "Diego ",
           Email= "dbav@gmail.com",
           Direcciones = Address,
           Telefonos=Telefonos

       };
```

in the view:..

```
.............

          angular.copy(result.data, $scope.data)   

..............
```

I have a copy of SettingsDetails in $scope.data but how can I get the values of the array? easily I can get the string of this way `{{ data.name }}` but the array in the same view?

Comment: can you post your code in Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get "460 jones" using `{{ data.Direcciones[0] }}`

For a better way, you can use ngRepeat directive. See this [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

for example:

```
Addresses:
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="address in data.Direcciones" >{{ address }}</li>
</ul>
Telefonos:
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="telefono in data.Telefonos" >{{ telefono }}</li>
</ul>
```